# Objective-C Clang-Format Method Brace Break

Tags: objective-c, xcode, lint, clang-format

I'm working with clang-format for my Objective-C project, but I'm having difficulty setting it up properly.

Here's my desired result:

```
- (NSString *)someMethod
{
  return @"My String";
}
```

Here's the actual result after formatting:

```
- (NSString *)someMethod {
  return @"My String";
}
```

Here's my `.clang-format` file:

```
BasedOnStyle: WebKit
AlignTrailingComments: true
ColumnLimit: 120
IndentWidth: 2
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PointerBindsToType: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
TabWidth: 2
UseTab: Never
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
```

What setting do I need to change to get the formatter to put a line break before the opening brace of an Objective-C method?

Answer (score 1):

For any fine-tuning of your `clang-format` you are much better off never to use `BasedOnStyle` because that for me just creates random and hard to debug results.

Easiest way to do this would be probably to set: `BreakBeforeBraces: Custom` and then set everything up the way you want it in as it says in [the documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

```
BraceWrapping:   
  AfterClass:      false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      false
  IndentBraces:    false
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my clang-format file accordingly, but I'm still not seeing the expected results. Does clang-format not work with Objective-C methods?

Comment: I actually don't use this format. I just tried it out and I can't make it format that way myself either.

Comment: I looked through the clang source and it should be supported, there is even a testcase for it:
`// BraceWrapping AfterFunction is respected for ObjC methods `
`Style = getGoogleStyle(FormatStyle::LK_ObjC);`
`Style.BreakBeforeBraces = FormatStyle::BS_Custom;`
`Style.BraceWrapping.AfterFunction = true;`
`verifyFormat("@implementation Foo\n"`
`"- (void)foo:(id)bar\n"`
`"{\n"`
`"}\n"`
`"@end\n");`

Comment: I don't have time to build and test llvm and clang right now.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the response. I talked with a colleague and determined it may be a bug in the version of clang-format that I'm using.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and source for this and I think there may be more than a couple of bugs in there. Unfortunately clang-format is very complicated to build and even filing a bug is a very cumbersome process.